# How to add a place to Google Places in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, post, geolocation, google-places-api

Could you point me to a reference on how to add a place to google places via JavaScript.

The only reference I found was on [google.developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#adding_a_place) but I don't know how to implement their solution in JavaScript:

```
POST https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=true_or_false&key=api_key HTTP/1.1
Host: maps.googleapis.com

{
  "location": {
    "lat": -33.8669710,
    "lng": 151.1958750
  },
  "accuracy": 50,
  "name": "Google Shoes!",
  "types": ["shoe_store"],
  "language": "en-AU"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Places Library of the JavaScript Maps API: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: there is no add functionality... (at least I can't find it)

Comment: Sorry, missed that you were looking for add functionality. JavaScript library doesn't support Place Reports. You might be better served with a server based solution.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just realized this will not work in a browser. I am doing this in an app which is ok, but if you're in a browser, this will violate the same origin policy. You can't post to an external URL and get a response.

Most if not all of the features in the JavaScript API are available via a web services API as well. Place actions are web service only. This is still achievable to be used client-side, since JavaScript can make HTTP requests. This is a great [getting started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) guide. A library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Ajax&redirect=no) can make things even easier. The JSON data in the example is a POST body. So you just need to create that as a string and send it via POST to the googleapis.com URL.